# For how long does the google bot wait after document ready before taking a snapshot of the webpage?

Tags: seo, javascript, web-crawlers, googlebot

As the google bot lets the JS do its work on the page while crawling, for how long does it wait to let the javascript execute after document ready ?

Suppose I have an AJAX response that takes longer than usual, how to make sure that the google bot crawls the content rich site (with the AJAX response) ?

I tried to do some experiment with that and found out that it waits for around 5 seconds. Is it a standard result for everyone ? Has google provided any documentation around this ?

Answer (score 3):

Googles bot will stick around as long as it needs to unless it times out or is stupidly slow. Regardless what the content is 5 seconds is far to slow and your site will suffer a user experience algorithm against it, which in term will effect your rankings, after-all, no one likes a slow website or page.

*Rough idea on page speed:*

- 0-1seconds awesome
- 1-2seconds good
- 2-3seconds ok
- 3-4seconds poor
- 4-5seconds very poor

In terms of the time allowance for Google's to take the snapshot there isn't one that is official, as far as I know. Unless your pages are usable within 3secs then you should fix the issue.

Comment: I've noticed that if you have JS timer events, the Google renderer appears to "bypass" the timer delay, executing the event immediately. eg. Timer event to generate page content set for 30 seconds - Google "Fetch and Render" returns _immediately_ with rendered content (not AJAX).

Comment: Yep, does the Google cache return AJAX?

Comment: For me, it did return the AJAX thing if I timeout the content in the limit of 5 seconds. What I did was, I made a timer that kept on printing a number, in incremental fashion, on the page. And after I did "Fetch and Render", the number I got on my page's snapshot was for 4.98 seconds. Thats why I assumed that they are have a settimeout of something around 5 seconds and they ignore the content loaded after that. Maybe...

Comment: On what authority is this answer based?

Comment: @LeeGee did you miss the part `***Rough*** idea on page speed:` and you could try using Google [1](https://www.hobo-web.co.uk/your-website-design-should-load-in-4-seconds/) [2](https://unbounce.com/landing-pages/2019-is-the-year-of-page-speed/) [3](https://neilpatel.com/blog/google-pagespeed-insights/)

Comment: @SimonHayter — I did, and thank you!