# Will Googlbot and other crawlers see content inserted by JavaScript on the window load event?

Tags: seo, html, googlebot, web-crawlers, javascript

Many robots, especially Googlebot, can read content written by JavaScript on sites.

There are some methods developed especially for site speed. At the beginning of these, do some operations after the `window.load` event.

```
window.addEventListener('load', fn);
```

If we do some actions that will change the integrity (content) of the site with these triggering events. Just as below;

```
window.addEventListener('load', fn);
var fn = function(){
 $.ajax({ url: 'localhost/dummy.txt', success: function(data) { 
   element.innerHTML = data;
 } });
}
```

An element with an empty content gained new content after the `window.load` event.

Can robots visiting this site detect this content?

Comment: Somewhat related: [For how long does the google bot wait after document ready before taking a snapshot of the webpage?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82459/for-how-long-does-the-google-bot-wait-after-document-ready-before-taking-a-snaps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can read it.

Easy and quick way to be 100% sure is use the URL Inspection Tool > Live Test on Google Search Console. You can see the final HTML and screenshot there.

Comment: Thank you for answer